# Capybara/Selenium vs Robot Framework for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, automated-tests

I have decided to choose Rspec/Capybara over Robot Framework for integration tests in Rails based App.

Previously, Robot Framework was used for integration testing in the project I am working on. As I now joined the team so I am trying to change it to Rspec-based integration testing using Capybara but I have to convince the top management that Rspec and Capybara is better option for Rails based application.

So basically I need a comparison table between these two frameworks which will tell that Rspec is better option than Python Robot Framework (if it is a better option).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After lot of research I was able to compile following comparison table between Rspec/Capybara vs Robot Framework 
I am answering this question in case somebody else need it.

[image]

Comment: please provide any research materials. and mostly your comparison is biased for rspec/capybara.

Comment: Having used both  - rspec much more briefly though - have to say your comparison table is actually not just biased, it's reversed in most points where rspeck is "winning" and robotframework not.